# OpenGL in Android. What is Configuration?

Tags: android

I am learning OpenGL programming in Android. I wrote a basic program that shows a cube on the screen, but it is displaying a black screen only. Can any one tell me what is the basic configuration of Eclipse for OpenGL?

Comment: Hi lalit nothing is needed to run opengl program in android as library is already available in sdk

Comment: Thnk you satya but what is the reason its showing only black screen.

Comment: will you share your code so that I can help you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest comparing your project to one of the many examples included with the SDK.

A basic triangle renderer can be found here:

```
%SDK%/samples/android-9/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TriangleActivity.java
%SDK%/samples/android-9/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TriangleRenderer.java
```

Also, keep in mind, if you are using the emulator, that it still does not support OpenGL ES 2.0. You need a device for that.